# How to use Topic Model (LDA) output to match and retrieve new, same-topic documents

Tags: text, lda, topic-modeling

I am using a LDA model on a corpus to learn the topics covered in it. I am using the gensim package (e.g., gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel); can easily use other versions of LDA if necessary.

My question is what is the most efficient way to use the parameterized model and/or topic words or topic IDs to find and retrieve new documents that contain the topic?

Concretely, I want to scrape a media API to find new articles (out-of-sample documents) that relate to my topics contained in my original corpus. Because I am doing this 'blind search', running the LDA on each new document may be too cumbersome; most new documents will not contain the topic.

Can of course simply retrieve new documents that contain one to n most of the frequent words of the LDA-learned topics; and then apply LDA to the returned documents for further confidence.

I am wondering if there is a more sophisticated method that gives better confidence that the new out-of-sample articles actually contain the same topic; as opposed to coincidentally containing one or two of the topic words.

Am looking at Topic Tiling algorithms but not sure if they are applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do not think you can search in the topic space without transforming everything in the topic space**. One could argue about creating functions that return the similarity in the topic space without transforming in the topic space (for instance with neural networks) but I think it is beyond the scope of the question.

Now since the above is not really helpful there are a lot of methods one can think of that will generate candidates better than simple keyword existence and I will write a couple of them.

#### Use the topics as documents

The topics are simply distributions over the words so you could use them as documents and compute the cosine similarity between them and a test document to get an estimate for the topic's probability in the document.

#### Use example documents

You could use `k` documents from the training set for each topic as examples and compute the similarity of those documents with a test document to get an estimate for the topic's probability in the document.

#### Use similarity hashing

With both of the above techniques you could also use [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), for instance [simhash](https://www.google.com/search?q=simhash&oq=sim&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j69i65j69i60l2.878j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), to more efficiently generate candidates from large corpora.

To make my last point clearer, I would use the following pipeline (in pseudo python)

```
# t is a topic
ht = simhash(t) # few bits here
candidates = []
final_texts = []
for text in new_texts:
    if simhash(text) == ht:
        candidates.append(text)
for text in candidates:
    topic_distribution = lda.infer(text)
    if argmax(topic_distribution) == t:
        final_textx.append(text)
```